# Python: Reading Relationships (Foreign Key Tables) of PostgreSQL Table

Tags: python, postgresql

I need to read the postgres database schema using python. I can already read the table and column names using,

```
cursor.execute(
  "select relname 
  from pg_class 
  where relkind='r' and relname !~ '^(pg_|sql_)';")
```

and,

```
cursor.execute("Select * FROM " + table_name)
colnames = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
```

I want to read the relationships between tables as well. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I'd start with `information_schema.key_column_usage` and `information_schema.table_constraints`.  Pay special attention to the columns "constraint_schema" and "table_schema". You can have identical table names in more than one schema.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this query it should work well:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT
    tc.constraint_name, tc.table_name, kcu.column_name, 
    ccu.table_name AS foreign_table_name,
    ccu.column_name AS foreign_column_name 
FROM 
    information_schema.table_constraints AS tc 
    JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
      ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
    JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu
      ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
WHERE constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND tc.table_name='+ table_name +'""")
```

Comment: Works well for me. I removed the `AND tc.table_name='+ table_name +'` part to get information on all tables.